# INSERT INTO SELECT takes long time on cluster

Tags: mysql, query-performance, mysql-cluster, percona-xtradb-cluster

My mysql cluster: `Ver 5.6.30-76.3-56 for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 (Percona XtraDB Cluster (GPL), Release rel76.3, Revision aa929cb, WSREP version 25.16, wsrep_25.16)`

I've a complicated sql query which inserts for about 36k rows into a table with this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO `sometable` (SELECT ...);
```

The select is a bit complicated but not slow (0.0023s) but the insert takes about 40-50s. The table is not in use when I'm inserting the rows.

My questions are:

- Can I speed it up somehow?
- The slow insert causes locking problems on the other tables (because of select)
- This workflow is good or bad practice? Is there any better?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

The table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `sometable` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `a` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b` smallint(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `c` smallint(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `d` smallint(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `e` smallint(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `f` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `country_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `city_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `g` smallint(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `h` smallint(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `i` smallint(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `j` smallint(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `k` smallint(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `l` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `m` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `n` text,
  `o` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `p` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `q` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `r` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `t` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `u` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `country_id` (`country_id`),
  KEY `city_id` (`city_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**UPDATE2:**

When I try to run the query I get an error in some cases:

```
ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

**MY SOLUTION:**

Here is my final solution if somebody interested in:
[gist](https://gist.github.com/belovai/a2adb81f2933ef0a499592e7cab58bf8)

The main problem was that while I fill `mytable` the other queries are stuck and the cluster had serious performance problems. In this solution I create a temporary table and fill it with data in "dirty read" mode, then I copy these data to `mytable` in chunks so it takes a bit more time but there is no performance problem and not stuck the queries.

Comment: mind sharing with us the `CREATE TABLE` statement of your table? (Include only the important stuff, like keys, indexed columns, indexes, etc.)

Comment: Please read this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ especially the part on query performance. Then please [edit] your question.

Comment: Are you sure your `SELECT` operation is really that fast? Read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/

Comment: @O.Jones I've updated the question with the schema. And yes, I've tried many times, the select is never more then 0.003s.

Comment: if this process is manual every time why dont you just `dump` the data and edit it and reinsert it ? it wont take much time when importing

Comment: @ArunpandianM It's not manual, I have to do it certain intervals.

Comment: Now try the `SELECT` this way:  `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` -- 3ms sounds like reading from the "Query cache".

Comment: Where is the `DELETE` of the old data?  Is it based on `id`?  Read about IODKU.

Comment: How far (ping time) apart are the nodes of the Cluster?  What, if anything are the _other_ nodes doing with this table at about the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `SELECT` operation that returns a row of the length you describe every 64 nanoseconds is very fast. That's what 36 kilorows in 2.3 milliseconds works out to.  It seems likely that your `SELECT` query timing doesn't account for the transport of the result set to the MySQL client. At any rate, using that performance as a comparison to an INSERT operation sets your expectations unreasonably high.

You might try issuing this command before starting your operation. It will allow your `SELECT` operation to proceed with fewer contentions with your application's traffic on the source tables for the `SELECT`. See here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-transaction.html

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
```

You might try a two step process, involving a temporary table.  This will have the advantage of not having to update all the indexes in `some_table` at the same time as the `SELECT` operation.  That operation will look like this.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE insert_batch AS SELECT ... ;
INSERT INTO some_table SELECT * FROM insert_batch;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE insert_batch;
```

You should understand that InnoDB posts your batch of insertions to your table as a single transaction.  If you can do this in a way that handles about 500 rows at a time rather than 36K, you'll have more transactions, but they will be smaller. That's generally a way to get higher throughput.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me really much. Based on this I've solved the problem. It's not so fast but there is no performance issue while running the procedure.

Comment: You're welcome. If you have time, can you leave a comment saying what you did and how much it improved performance?

Comment: I've updated the question with my solution. If you have any comment about it I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, this may be a viable solution.  First, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

1. Load your corrections into a temp table (or non-replicated MyISAM table).
2. Loop through the temp table (using code similar to that link).  Pick 100 rows at a time.
3. Do the `INSERT ... SELECT ...` of 100 rows in a *separate* transaction.

This technique may (or may not) take longer than 40-50s, but at least is much less likely to timeout or deadlock.

In general, avoid running any transaction that lasts longer than a few seconds.  This link is somewhat generic on how to "chunk" lengthy (and repetitive) operations to avoid long transactions.

Comment: Thank you, I've used chunks idea finally.